# Add a Button into PrefrenceScreen : Android

Tags: android, onclick, android-preferences, onclicklistener

Hi i want to add a button into prefrencescreen, i got success into add a button into the prefrence but i could not get onClick event. i have attached my code a pic of prefence screen

setting.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Application Details">

    <Preference android:key="type" 
                android:title="Type"
                android:summary="" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Notification Settings">

    <ListPreference android:key="sendNotificationType"
                    android:title="Status Notification For"
                    android:dialogTitle="Status Notification For" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

settingdetail.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Type"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/setFromTimeBtn"
    android:text="Summary"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buyItNowBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/buyItNowBtnTxt"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

and the onCreate Method of prefenceActivity Class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.setting);
    setContentView(R.layout.settingview);

    Preference typePref = (Preference) findPreference("type");
    typePref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.settingdetail);
typePref.setSelectable(true);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyItNowBtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG,"TEST");
        Toast.makeText(Setting.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

}
```

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Give Toast as like this and try it once.Toast.makeText(Setting.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Does  Button btn has some value..have u debugged it??

Comment: button has id but i could not get the onClick.

Comment: Try this way..btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    }
   });

Comment: i could not get btn. it give me NullPointerException at this line btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: @HChouhan btn is Null then for Sure!!!

Comment: yeah i am getting null for button.

Answer (score 5):

This thread is stale, but since there is no solution yet, here is how I succeeded:

**1. Set the button click listener**

There are two ways to set the click listener for a button, either programmatically or via XML.

*Programmatically:* In your custom preference, override `onBindView` and attach the listener there:

```
@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    View button = view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "button click listener works!");
        }
    });
    super.onBindView(view);
}
```

*Via XML:* Add `android:onClick="yourMethodName"` to the layout definition of the `Button` element (which is part of the layout for your preference, see below) and implement the method in your `PreferenceActivity`as described here: [Responding to Click Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents)

**2. Fix OnPreferenceClickListener**

Now the button click listener should work, but the Preference's `OnPreferenceClickListener` will not work anymore. In order to fix this, add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the top element in the layout file for your preference:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:maxLines="4" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

(No `android:onClick="yourMethodName"` here as I chose to do it programmatically.)

**3. Attach the Layout**

Finally you need to set this layout to your preference XML file:
Add `android:layout="@layout/myLayoutName"` or alternatively set it via `setLayoutResource` as you construct the preference in your `PreferenceFragment`.

Answer (score 2):

Implement OnPreferenceClickListener in preferenceActivity

```
private Preference mBuyPreference = null;
mLogoutPreference = findPreference(yourkey);
mBuyPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
if (preference == mBuyPreference) {

    try {
        //Do Something
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: but that is on click on row but i want to get click event on button only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the onClick() handler, override the onPreferenceTreeClick method in your PreferenceActivity. There you will get the clicked preference object and you can check its key.

```
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {

 if (preference.getKey().equals("key")) {           
       // do something
       return true;
 }

 return false;
}
```

Comment: can you give me a example of that.

Comment: u can try PreferenceClickListener mBuyPrefernce.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

I've solved half of your problem by creating a custom preference like this -

In order to get to this, I created a custom preference like this -

```
public class CustomPreference extends Preference {

private LinearLayout mWidgetContainer;
private View mRowView;

public CustomPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mRowView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.preferences_row_view, parent, false);

    mWidgetContainer = (LinearLayout) mRowView.findViewById(android.R.id.widget_frame);

    Button button = new Button(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_row_bg);
    button.setTextSize(14);
    button.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BuyScreenActivity.class);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    button.setText("Buy now");
    mWidgetContainer.addView(button);

    return mRowView;
}
}
```

Then in your settings xml file you can create a setting like

```
<package.of.your.java.file.CustomPreference 
    android:key="type" 
    android:title="Type"
    android:summary="" />
```

And my preferences_row_view.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="50dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That will do.

But there is one more issue I'm facing which I've posted here on SO.

[Add a button in Preference Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194944/add-a-button-in-preference-row)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyItNowBtn);
```

do this

```
  Button btn = (Button)typePref.getView(view, viewGroup );
```