# Add a button in Preference Row

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want a button in my Settings screen. This exact question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514005/add-a-button-into-prefrencescreen-android). But unfortunately has no answers. :(

[image]

In order to get to this, I created a custom preference like this -

```
  public class CustomPreference extends Preference {

    private LinearLayout mWidgetContainer;
    private View mRowView;

    public CustomPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mRowView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.preferences_row_view, parent, false);

        mWidgetContainer = (LinearLayout) mRowView.findViewById(android.R.id.widget_frame);

        Button button = new Button(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_row_bg);
        button.setTextSize(14);
        button.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BuyScreenActivity.class);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        button.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        button.setText("Buy now");
        mWidgetContainer.addView(button);

        return mRowView;
    }
}
```

This does work. But it behaves strange. As you can see on click of that button I'm taking the user to Activity called `BuyScreenActivity`. The strange part is when I press back on `BuyScreenActivity`, I come back to my Settings screen but `onDestroy` and `onStop` of `BuyScreenActivity` is not called at all. Why would it behave that way?

If I scroll down the settings screen, `onStop` & `onDestroy` will then be called. Why does this have to behave that way?

Comment: You should just expose `setOnClickListener` of button to whatever activity is holding the custom preference. Let the host activity decide what to do on the click event.

Comment: I will try that and get back.

Comment: I tried. I can't seem to get reference to the button even in onStart & onResume. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that is happening exactly, but if it bothers you, just override onBackPressed() in BuyScreenActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), SettingsACtivity.class));
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that you're only getting to BuyScreen through Settings.
If you're not, then it's easy enough to put the name of the previous activity into the intent data, and switch that to get to the desired activity.